# handle multiple angular calls when more submit buttons available

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a form which contains one drop down, check box and four buttons. When any of the action is performed (check/uncheck or drop down selection or button click), it has to trigger a service call and the below section should be updated. There may be a chance that the multiple actions can be performed one after other immediately. If this is the case, http call should be triggered only after last activity.

Would be nice if there is any workable idea for this. I feel the timeout can helpful to wait for user to complete all activities (waiting for certain time after each activity) and call http service.

Comment: Some code would help a lot with this. Can you add a version your work so far?

Comment: Add submit button. Otherwise it will be called everytime. Eventually you can add some kind of timeout to `$watch` function (I assume if you're using Angular, you're using `$watch` to check if scope changes).

Answer (score 0):

I guess thats what you need:

```
var timeoutPromise;
var delayInMs = 2000;
$scope.$watch("your_form_scope", function(newValue, oldValue) {
  $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);  //does nothing, if timeout alrdy done
  timeoutPromise = $timeout(function(){   //Set timeout
     //your code
  },delayInMs);
});
```